# Выделение памяти realloc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, память, realloc

Всем привет!
Есть такой код, перегрузка оператора ввода в собственном классе строки, пишу для изучения:

```
 friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, MyString& input_string) {
     char* input_data = nullptr;
     int counter = 0;
     char symbol;
     while (true) {
         if ((symbol = stream.get()) != '\n') {
             input_data = (char* )realloc(input_data, ++counter);
             static int a = strlen(input_data);
             input_data[counter - 1] = symbol;
         } 
         else {
             input_data[counter] = 0;
             break;
         }
     }
     input_string.string = input_data;
     input_string.size = input_string.length();
     return stream;
 }
```

Ожидалось, что переменная `a` после первого вызова станет равна 1, и после каждого последующего вызова `realloc` в цикле будет увеличиваться на единицу.
Однако, *Visual Studio 2013* считает по-другому, и выделяет сразу *16 байт* памяти, а после 4-х итераций как раз-таки выделяет по одному байту. Таким образом получается, что всегда в запасе есть лишние 12 байт мусора...
Собственно вопрос - дело в компиляторе? Или где-то мой косяк? Спасибо.

Comment: `strlen` - не меряет размер данных вот и всё. `realloc` - на работу   `strlen` не влияет. `strlen` - показывает длинну ascii-z строки. А если её нету, то размер строки выдаст некорректно, или вообще исключение даст.

Comment: Функция памяти вам даёт "случайно" разные участки памяти, а в них могут попадаться разного размера строки. Поскольку несмотря на хаотичность "кучи" - закономерность в ней может прослеживаться - вы получаете "генератор псевдослучайных чисел". При чём т.к. вероятность встретить ноль - большая - то вы получаете расстояние в байтах до ближайшего "нуля" (где-то в пределах 0-32) в памяти которую выдал диспечер.

Comment: Если вам нужно действительно знать размер участка - советую использовать LocalAlloc c параметром FIXED, и  LocalReAlloc и LocalSize даст вам то что вы хотите. Или их аналог HeapAlloc.

Comment: даже без `strlen` в отладчике видно, что размер выделенной памяти вовсе не 1 байт. Изменил вопрос и привел более полный код для понимания того, что там происходит

Comment: `static int a`??? К чему здесь `static`? И какую вообще роль играет это `a`? Зачем вам понадобилось определять размер блока памяти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `strlen` определяет длину строки и ограничена нахождением первого нулевого байта.
Вместо `size_t strlen(char const*)` предлагаю использовать `size_t _msize(void*)` в Windows или `size_t malloc_usable_size(void*)` в Linux, обе функции находятся в `<malloc.h>`. Таким образом вы узнаете выделены объем памяти.

Comment: _msize действительно показывает верный размер выделенной памяти, спасибо!

Comment: есть ли вариант инициализировать выделенный байт нулем, чтобы не наблюдать в отладчике [лишние символы](http://prntscr.com/ji6m32)?

Comment: @Иван, после выделения памяти сделайте следующее: if(input_data != nullptr){ input_data[0] = 0; }

Comment: Бессмысленный ответ на бессмысленный вопрос. Автору вообще не нужна функция определения размера памяти, ибо он этот размер знает и так.

Comment: @Ant, если вы прочитаете внимательнее вопрос, то поймете зачем. `realloc` в данной реализации должен выделять по 1 байту памяти за каждый проход. Однако, функция `strlen` показывала размер выделенной памяти 16. Как оказалось, размер выделенной памяти необходимо определять в помощью `_msize`, и оказалось, что все работает как задумано. И да, меня смущал тот факт, что выделяется 16 байт вместо одного, поэтому вопрос вовсе не бессмысленный, как и ответ. Бессмысленным оказалось лишь ваше появление здесь, которое не принесло пользы. "Ибо он этот размер знает и так" - хотел проверить, а знаю ли.

Comment: @Иван: Зачем нужна функция `_msize` для "выделения одного байта памяти за каждый проход"? В коде это уже и так успешно делается, и при этом никакой `strlen` и никакой `_msize` не используется. Значение переменной `a` нигде не используется вообще. Размер для выделения определяется переменной `counter`. Зачем здесь какой-то `_msize`?

Comment: @Ant еще раз, эта переменная `a` и функция `_msize` были добавлены исключительно для отладки, чтобы удостовериться, что действительно выделяется 1 байт, а не 16, как я подумал, исходя из [информации](https://prnt.sc/ji6m32), предоставленной отладчиком. Юрий Коротков и остальные объяснили, с чем связано такое поведение. Вот и все) `_msize` - именно для _проверки_ того, что действительно выделяется `counter` байт, а не для собственно выделения.

Comment: @Иван, в определении размера выделенной памяти вы используете неверное определение (strlen или то что вам пишет отладчик). в действительности, выделяется память верно (1 байт в вашем примере), в ответе указано как правильно определить размер выделенной памяти.